# Apache Camel - select the longest matching prefix when using matchOnUriPrefix with overlapping prefixes

Tags: routes, apache-camel

With camel and dynamically created routes I want to have multiple specific routes and a single catch-all route that matches everything else.

For example:

```
Catch-all route:
"jetty:0.0.0.0:8080/myservice?matchOnUriPrefix=true" -> general response

Specific routes (created dynamically later)
"jetty:0.0.0.0:8080/myservice/route1?matchOnUriPrefix=true" -> response for route 1
"jetty:0.0.0.0:8080/myservice/route2?matchOnUriPrefix=true" -> response for route 2
```

Problem:

If routes are created as in the example above then Camel doesn't guarantee which route will be selected *e.g.* for request /myservice/route1 - it can be either 'route1' or 'catch-all' whichever is found first in a set (*i.e.* unordered). Depending on the route name it request will go to catch-all or to the specific route.

**Is there a way of forcing Camel to find the more concrete (longer) route first?**

- The routes are added dynamically so I cannot use from(catchAllUrl).choice() as I don't know the conditions upfront
- There are way of manually parsing the URL in catch-all and redirecting to the correct route, but I'd like to use "the Camel way" if it exists.
- There may be routes other than 'myservice' so I wouldn't want to handle it globally in onError as 404 (if it's even possible)

Comment: What version of Camel do you use?

Comment: I'm using the latest version of Camel - 2.20.1